# Facing CORS errors despite having the origins and fetch() properly configured

Tags: express, cors, fetch

I have the UI and the server deployed on Render. My frontend has a form that sends data to the server and the server sends it to MongoDB Atlas if it's correct. "It works on my machine" perfectly. But not on a real server.

that´s my HTML forms:

```
    <form data-create-account method="POST">
            <label for="userName">Your name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" placeholder="Name Example" data-input-user-name>
            <span>erro, nome inválido</span>
            <label for="userEmail">Your email</label>
            <input type="email" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" placeholder="example@email.com" data-input-user-email>
            <span>erro, e-mail inválido</span>
            <label for="userPassword">Sua senha</label>
            <input type="password" id="userPassword" name="userPassword" data-input-user-password placeholder="••••••••">
            <span>erro, senha: 8+ caracteres, 1 letra e 1 número</span>
            <button type="submit">Create</button>
        </form>
```

The fetch getting and sending the data from the form to the server:

```
fetch('https://easy-bank-server.onrender.com/create-account', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            mode: 'cors', // Habilita o modo CORS
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                if (data.ok) {
                ...
                }
```

my cors on the server:

```
app.use(cors({origin: '*'}))
```

And that`s the goddamn error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://easy-bank-server.onrender.com/create-account' from origin 'https://easy-bank-ui.onrender.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I've been trying to insert all kinds of oringins but it never works

Comment: _"my cors on the server:"_ - which server; the one serving `easy-bank-server.onrender.com`, or `easy-bank-ui.onrender.com`?

Comment: @CBroe so, the easy-bank-ui.onrender.com is the frontend that makes a request to the easy-bank-server.onrender.com server, and for some reason, cors is blocking it somewhere. I really don't now what to do... below my code if you'd like to check it out:
https://github.com/Gustavo361/easy-bank-landing-page (frontend)
https://github.com/Gustavo361/easy-bank-server (server)